# Cannot Implement GoogleApiClient.ServerAuthCodeCallbacks in android

Tags: android, google-api-client, google-signin

I am implementing Google plus login system to my android app by following the tutorial of google developer at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in

According to the tutorial, I should implement:

```
GoogleApiClient.ServerAuthCodeCallbacks
```

interface to enable server-side API access for the android app. However, 'ServerAuthCodeCallbacks' interface does not exist in the GoogleApiClient library, even in the latest version of the library.

Does anybody have the same issue? Or, am I missing something?

Any input will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check that you're using `com.google.android.gms:play-services` of version at least `7.3.0`, there is this class in class in package `com.google.android.gms.common.api` in sub-dependency `play-services-base`

Comment: @MarekSebera It turned out that the current version of play-service was 6.x which is lower than 7.3.0, hence not working. I updated the play-service version to the latest version, and it finally works. I very appreciate your comment. I will accept your advice as an answer if you post this comment as "your answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example implementation on GitHub: [github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android/blob/master/app/build.gradle)

Your dependency on `com.google.android.gms:play-services` must be at least of version `7.0.0` (currently latest is version `7.5.0`)

Class itself is currently placed in package `com.google.android.gms.common.api` in Maven sub-dependency `play-services-base`

So for example like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

Also see current Developer documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: If anybody is still stuck on this, GoogleApiClient.ServerAuthCodeCallbacks has been deprecated in Play Services 8.3 and removed in Play Services 8.4. Implementation using current API [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/v1/offline-access)